# Center just one \section*{}

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, sections-paragraphs

This is my document format:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep = period}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{lastnote}
\newenvironment{scilastnote}{%
\setcounter{lastnote}{\value{enumiv}}%
\addtocounter{lastnote}{+1}%
\begin{list}%
{\arabic{lastnote}.}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{.22in}}
{\setlength{\labelsep}{.5em}}}
{\end{list}}


\title{\normalsize\textbf{Title Text}}

\author{Author Stuff}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\textit{Info Text}}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}

\definecolor{blueline}{rgb}{0.392, 0.584, 0.929}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2.0pt \color{blueline}}


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtr}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}


\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document} 
\date{\vspace{-7ex}}
    \maketitle

\section*{Abstract}  %<-- This needs to be centered....
```

Now I want to center only my first section.
I've tried these and none of them worked:

```
\center
\centering
\centering{}
\centerline{}
\section*{\hfill Abstract \hfill}
```

Any suggestions... please?

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! I think a full [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) might be helpful here. Please don't give us your whole document, but it'd be nice to see your preamble and have something we can actually compile and pull about

Comment: You can use `\titleformat` also mid-document to change the formatting of a section: `... \begin{document}
\begingroup
  \titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalsize\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase}
  \section*{Abstract}
  text
\endgroup
\section*{First section} ...`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your use case, I see no real need for using `\section*` to set the abstract. Since `\section*` doesn't usually end up in the ToC nor does it use any form of counter that can be referenced, just set it with the same formatting inside a `center` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec,lipsum}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

%\section*{Abstract}  %<-- This needs to be centered....
\begin{center}
  \normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase{ABSTRACT}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

If you truly want it formatted like an abstract, use the `abstract` environment with an updated `\abstractname`:

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\normalsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase{Abstract}}

% ...

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
```

[image]

<sub>Of course, for one-time use content you may just as well write `ABSTRACT` instead of `\MakeUppercase{Abstract}`.</sub>